# How to create a JavaScript function expression with a name and body stored in different variables?

Tags: javascript, function

I have function name stored in a variable like `var funcName = "dep1"`and function body stored in a different variable like `var funcBody = function(){};`

How to create dep1 function from above variables?

Comment: That's not a normal thing to do; there are ways of doing it but they would generally be considered bad practice. What is it that you're really trying to do?

Comment: im not sure what is it that you are trying to do, but i have a feeling that an if-else clause will serve you much better than dynamically created functions.

Comment: @Pointy: I am trying to simulate angular dependency injection.I have functions and names stored in an object as key value pairs. I have to resolve them in other function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var funcBody = function() {
  document.write('hallo')
};

var funcName = "dep1";

this[funcName] = funcBody;

dep1();
```